# django queryset to json list to js array

Tags: javascript, json, django

I am fairly new to json and javascript and I've been trying to pass django queryset to a js array.

I've managed to pass the .values queryset to javascript through json.

Django to JSON code

```
def getPorts(request):
    ports = Port.objects.all()

    data = serializers.serialize('json', ports, fields=('name'))

    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

JS where I am currently stuck at

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'getPorts,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
            var ports = JSON.parse(result)
            console.log(ports[0]);
        }
    });
```

ports[0] gives me something like
{model: "Coordinator.port", pk: 1, fields: {…}}
fields:
{name: "Fa0/1"}
model:"Coordinator.port"
pk:1
**proto**:Object

Is there a way to extract only the 'name' attribute? I've been trying to treat it like a 2d array but I haven't really been successful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ports[0]['fields']['name']
```

If you want more control over the serialization format, you should look at django-rest-framework.